# How to construct ajax payload dynamically with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

So with my code below - each checkbox that is checked results in a ajax request being sent.  However what I want is a single ajax request with all the names of the checkboxes being sent in the payload.  How exactly can I do this?  In Python I would just create a list or dictionary and send that - but not sure how to do this with js.

```
function save_product(data) {
    $('input[class="product"]:checked').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/edit_view/",
            data: {
                product_name:name,
            },
            success: function(data){}
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want is a single ajax request with all the names of the checkboxes being sent in the payload
>
> In Python I would just create a list or dictionary and send that - but not sure how to do this with js

Well intuitively just like in Python actually

---

```
function save_product(data) {
  var products = []
  $('input[class="product"]:checked').each(function(chk) {
    var product = chk.val()
    products.push(product)
  });

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/edit_view/",
    data: {
      product_name: products,
    },
    success: function(data){
      // Handle response
    }
  });
}
```

You can take advantage of various js sugar, and jquery sugar. `.map` is a great tool to start thinking in functional programming. Like so :

```
var products = $('input[class="product"]:checked').map(function(chk) {
  return chk.val()
})
// products === [1, 7, 12]
// assuming you put the product.id inside checkbox value= attribute
```

@Karan Patel answer above uses a lambda expression, which is ES6 and might not be well suited for you if you do not [transpile](https://babeljs.io/) your code before running it in the browser. But sure you can simplify it with `chk => chk.val()` being equivalent of `function(chk) { return chk.val() }`, like so :

```
var products = $('input[class="product"]:checked').map(chk => chk.val())
```

---

**Bonus :**

1)

If you're starting javascript, you should from now start leaving the "callback pattern" for every async operations, and start using at least "Promise pattern". Read [this](https://medium.com/@theflyingmantis/callbacks-vs-promises-and-basics-of-js-80d3d1515e81).

Like so :

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"/edit_view/",
  data: {
    product_name: products,
  }
})
.then(function(data) {
  // Handle response
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // Handle error
});
```

2)

You're targetting and grouping product values with `input[class="product"]` which you can simplify `input.product`. **Be very careful with [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)**, as in your syntax, `<input class="product custom-product">` **won't match** your selector (your targetting **exactly** `product` word in class. But in your precise case, you might want to target more semantically and accurately your input's with something like `form.my-form input[name=product_name]` to target

```
<form class="my-form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="product_name" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="product_name" value="2" />
</form>
```

(name attribute is precisely designed to identify inputs, uniquely)

3) And finally, just because you have to hear it, jQuery is not required for such a simple operation nowadays

Here I'm using plain js to get values, and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to ajax the stuff.

```
var productsChks = document.querySelectorAll('input.product')
var products = products.map(productChk => productChk.value)

axios.get('/edit_view/', {data: products})
.then(function(data) {
  // Handle data
})
```

Be careful of [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall)

Note you can also use a native browser API for ajax, [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), stil being careful of [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) and the potential need of a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)